# Is there pluggable online python console?

Tags: python, django, shell, console

I'm thinking if there already is some sort of online live python console (web-based) with open source code available. Anyone know of anything?
It would be really useful to have console in Django admin (like running *python manage.py shell* on the server's terminal), so it would be great to have django/any wsgi aplication, that can be used to enable web based live console access.

Thanks

Comment: Have you ever tried http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the Werkzug debugger.

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/

http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/debug/

It's got an interactive javascript based in-browser debugger for your WSGI projects, among many other great tools. Fantastic stuff.

For Django specifically, there's also RunServerPlus, which is part of the django-extensions package.

https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Python Anywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com/). You can run python web apps, you get an SQL database, and you get a bash shell in your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [python shell](http://shell.appspot.com/) from Google. There's a link to source code at the top. Loading Django environment into it might be not very easy but I believe it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your desire but you might take a look at Chrome extension : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia

Answer (score -3):

There is a great website called [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com). It teaches the fundamentals of Python, Ruby, Javascript, and HTML/CSS.
They also have online consoles for each of the languages they teach, excluding HTML/CSS. This website is [Codecademy Labs](http://labs.codecademy.com). Codecademy Labs has a console you can type directly in, and an editor that displays output in the console. I hope that this helped you find what you were looking for!

Comment: The question is asking about browser-based Python consoles that they can plug into their own website, not consoles on other people's sites.